Suppressing logo on specific Quarto (reveal.js) slides
I would like to remove my logo from a specific slide in my Quarto reveal.js presentation.
I've included a logo in my Quarto reveal.js slide deck as follows:
---
format:
  revealjs:
    logo: logo.png
---

This produces a logo for every slide in my presentation. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to suppress or hide the logo on a specific slide. If someone out there has any insights, it would be greatly appreciated.

One solution is to set the background-color colour of the slide you want to hide the logo of, and use CSS to force the logo to be underneath the slide background. You can use any background color (I've used white here to match the background of the other slides).
Quarto document:
---
format:
  revealjs:
    logo: logo.png
    css: custom.css
---

## Slide 1

Logo

## Slide 2 {background-color="white"}

No logo

and the custom.css file:
.reveal .slide-logo {
  z-index: -999 !important;
}

Slide 1:

Slide 2:

(Solution inspired by a bug in an older version of Quarto which was fixed here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/4031)
